# Retrieve a set of string with unique substring

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

I have a set of strings in R. In the form of: `"X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt"`. I want to retrieve the set of strings containing just the first occurrence of a string. It depends on the 4th field. In this set for e.g. I have multiple string with X-Y-Z.3000....." I want only the first one having id = 3000, the same for the others.

For reproducibility:

```
X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt
X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.F-N.fC-G.txt
X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt
X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.B-SX-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt
```

So at the end I would only the first anche 3th string

```
X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt
X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt
```

Comment: Not clear, what is the expected output, for these 4 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract "*4th field"* which is 2nd field if we split on `"."`, then exclude duplicated items:

```
# data
x <- c("X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt",
       "X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.F-N.fC-G.txt",
       "X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt",
       "X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.B-SX-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt")

x[ !duplicated(sapply(strsplit(x, ".", fixed = "TRUE"), "[", 2)) ]
# [1] "X-Y-Z.3000.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt"
# [2] "X-Y-Z.3008.F.PP0016-C.A-SL-0433.P-N.fC-G.txt"
```